# Setting Radio button using Ruby and Watir

Tags: ruby, radio-button, watir-webdriver

Right i am having issues with a section of code. I know how to set radio buttons i can do it on most websites. But when trying to set a value given by this code below i cannot make it work. I have tried "waiting until", "parent setting" using the label ect and searched through all sorts. Could any one point me in the right direction.

```
<div class="CheckBoxContainer">

<ol>
    <li>
        <span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></span>
        <input class="styled" type="radio" value="1" name="clocksource"></input>
        <label class="dialogRT">

            Internal

        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></span>
        <input class="styled" type="radio" value="3" name="clocksource"></input>
        <label class="dialogRT">

            External AES50

        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -50px;"></span>
        <input class="styled" type="radio" checked="checked" value="2"       name="clocksource"></input>
        <label class="dialogRT">

            External Snake

        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I get this error :

```
[remote server] file:///var/folders/81/j_87g_h12_x7bkl2w58zwqr00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20131024-1211-10eh16l/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8210:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Thanks

Maximillion

Comment: It worked fine for me using your html snippet. Perhaps you need to provide more of the page, for example the related stylesheets.

Comment: Right ok, I can't do that at the moment, the strange thing is if i do a 
'browser.radio(:name => 'clocksource', :value => '1').exist?'
on all three options they all say true, yet try and alter them and it says not visible.

Comment: Also when I do a .value it claims a value of one when the display clearly shows 3 is highlighted.

Comment: `.exist?` only checks that the element exists in the DOM. It does not check if the element is visible to the user, which is what your exception is complaining about. If you use `.visible?` instead, it will likely be `false`. When you did `.value` were you doing `browser.radio(:name => 'clocksource').value`? If so, then getting "1" is correct. Watir returns the first matching radio button, not the radio button that is checked.

Comment: Ah I see misunderstanding on my part there, you are right .visible shows up as false for all three. I was doing .value no question mark, don't know if that makes any difference. I have very little knowledge of web page code, why would something which is an active control not be visible? something to do with code construction?

Comment: For the `.value` part, the question mark is not actually part of the code; it was meant to be the punctuation of the sentence. An active control should be visible, which means there could be a bug (in one of the gems) or we are interpreting the information/code incorrectly. Did you try stepping through your script manually using `irb` to verify that the control is visible/usable when expected?

Comment: I tried stepping through with IRB and they always appear as not visible despite them being active controls. Even if i interact with the page and click the radio button then see if they are visible they are still false

Comment: Seems rather strange. I would suggest creating a page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ah i didn't create the page not really possible.

Comment: Is it a public page that we can access? Alternatively, try saving the entire page (you may also need the stylesheets and any javascript). Then see if you can reproduce the problem on there.

Comment: Try using .present? instead of .exists?. exists tells you if the element exists in the page BUT does not distinguish wether the element is clickable or if it hidden or controlled by some js event. .present? does a .exist? and then additionally checks if it is .enabled? and only returns true if both conditions are met. If it turns out the element is not visible, when it does become visible on the screen the dom may not be being updated to reflect this from the test suite, so although it looks to you like it is on the page, webdriver just throws a hissy fit.

Comment: Ok sound I will try this, we had a look at the code and they are definitely active from the load. It may be that I just have to leave it and move on. But we have other pages which operate the same and they are ok. I might have to learn some HTML and Java script so I can diagnose this kinda stuff.

Comment: Yeah no matter what i do they are never visible, despite the fact you can click them, we checked the html and they are not hidden so i would say it is an issue with ruby or watir-webdriver. bit annoying but never-mind. Still works for other bits of work. Thanks for all your help, I learned something regardless. If you ever hear of this being sorted or other people talking about it let me know. Cheers

Comment: Check to see if there is more than one of them.  `b.radios(:name => 'clocksource').size.  Without seeing the actual page and being able to play with it, it's very hard for me to troubleshoot directly.

Comment: There is only one set with the name, but thanks anyway. I actually found the issue, it turned out to be the javascript overlay which they were using to make the page look nicer, this was tricking watir into thinking the control was not active.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a timing issue. Try this:

```
Watir::Wait.until { @browser.element.visible?, thing  }
```

Comment: I actually tried that already, i found the issue was actually down to the implementation of the page i was trying to test. The elements were never visible due to the style sheets.